# How do you click a menuItem in NavigationView on Android when testing with Espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

How do you click on a menuItem in a NavigationView from the design library using Espresso? It works fine on a larger devices where the whole menu is visible but in landscape or smaller devices the bottom of my menu is off the screen and I can not figure out a way to scroll/swipe to these menuItems so I can click on them.

Calling:

```
onView(withText(R.string.contact_us)).perform(scrollTo()).check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(click());
```

Generates the following:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed
>   because the target view does not match one or more of the following
>   constraints: (view has effective visibility=VISIBLE and is descendant
>   of a: (is assignable from class: class android.widget.ScrollView or is
>   assignable from class: class android.widget.HorizontalScrollView))
>   Target view: "NavigationMenuItemView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE,
>   width=888, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false,
>   has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true,
>   is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false,
>   is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false,
>   has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=1653.0, text=Contact Us,
>   input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"

NavigationView inherits from FrameLayout and are doing a canvas shift to scroll.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html

I tried to write a customViewAction to slowly scroll the screen using the below action and check if the menuItem is visible and if not keep scrolling, but I could not get it to work.

```
CoordinatesProvider coordinatesProvider = new CoordinatesProvider() {
        public float[] calculateCoordinates(View view) {
            float[] xy = GeneralLocation.BOTTOM_CENTER.calculateCoordinates(view);
            xy[0] += 0.0F * (float)view.getWidth();
            xy[1] += -0.083F * (float)view.getHeight();
            return xy;
        }
    };

onView(withId(R.id.navigation_view)).perform(new GeneralSwipeAction(Swipe.SLOW,
                             coordinatesProvider, GeneralLocation.TOP_CENTER, Press.FINGER));

onView(withText(R.string.contact_us)).check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(click());
```

Has anyone figured out how to test navigationView on Espresso yet? I am pretty sure my logic behind the customViewAction would work but I can not get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, I used a custom viewAction

```
public static ViewAction swipeForTextToBeVisible(final String text, final long millis, final View navigationView) {
        return new ViewAction() {
            @Override
            public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
                return isRoot();
            }

            @Override
            public String getDescription() {
                return "swipe for a specific view with text <" + text + "> during " + millis + " millis.";
            }

            @Override
            public void perform(final UiController uiController, final View view) {
                uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle();
                final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                final long endTime = startTime + millis;
                final Matcher<View> viewMatcher = withText(text);

                do {
                    boolean returnAfterOneMoreSwipe = false; //not sure why I have to do one more swipe but it works

                    for (View child : TreeIterables.breadthFirstViewTraversal(view)) {
                        // found view with required ID
                        if (viewMatcher.matches(child) && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                            returnAfterOneMoreSwipe = true;
                        }
                    }

                    CoordinatesProvider coordinatesProvider = new CoordinatesProvider() {
                        public float[] calculateCoordinates(View view) {
                            float[] xy = GeneralLocation.BOTTOM_CENTER.calculateCoordinates(view);
                            xy[0] += 0.0F * (float)view.getWidth();
                            xy[1] += -0.083F * (float)view.getHeight();
                            return xy;
                        }
                    };

                    //Below code is c/p from perform in android/support/test/espresso/action/GeneralSwipeAction.class
                    float[] startCoordinates = coordinatesProvider.calculateCoordinates(navigationView);
                    float[] endCoordinates = GeneralLocation.TOP_CENTER.calculateCoordinates(navigationView);
                    float[] precision = Press.FINGER.describePrecision();
                    Swiper.Status status = Swiper.Status.FAILURE;

                    for(int tries = 0; tries < 3 && status != Swiper.Status.SUCCESS; ++tries) {
                        try {
                            status = Swipe.SLOW.sendSwipe(uiController, startCoordinates, endCoordinates, precision);
                        } catch (RuntimeException var9) {
                            throw (new PerformException.Builder()).withActionDescription(this.getDescription()).withViewDescription(HumanReadables.describe(navigationView)).withCause(var9).build();
                        }

                        int duration = ViewConfiguration.getPressedStateDuration();
                        if(duration > 0) {
                            uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast((long)duration);
                        }
                    }
                    //End c/p from android/support/test/espresso/action/GeneralSwipeAction.class

                    if (returnAfterOneMoreSwipe) {
                        return;
                    }

                    uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(50);
                }
                while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime);

                // timeout happens
                throw new PerformException.Builder()
                        .withActionDescription(this.getDescription())
                        .withViewDescription(HumanReadables.describe(view))
                        .withCause(new TimeoutException())
                        .build();
            }
        };
    }
```

I do not love this solution, it is not the cleanest since for some reason I have to swipe again after it says its visible but it works.

To use it you call it with the following:

```
onView(isRoot()).perform(CustomViewActions.swipeForTextToBeVisible(getActivity().getString(R.string.contact_us),2000, getActivity().findViewById(R.id.navigation_view)));
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me even when menu item was not visible (somewhere down in the list)

onView(withId(R.id.nav_view)).perform(NavigationViewActions.navigateTo(R.id.nav_login));

Comment: Works like a charm with a single line! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the espresso-contrib:

```
import android.support.test.espresso.contrib.DrawerActions;
```

To open the menu, you can do this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout)).perform(DrawerActions.open());
```

You can scroll down to the menu item and check whether it is displayed:

```
onView(withId(R.id.my_menu_item)).perform(scrollTo()).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

And to click on menu item:

```
onView(withId(R.id.my_menu_item)).perform(click());
```